# Strange behavior of NavigationBar after multiple push and pop with animation NO. iOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

**Problem while multiple pop and push operation performed on UINavigationController programmatically with animation NO. ( iOS7 iPhone Only )**

**Source Code**
https://github.com/abhishek9284/NavigationBarTest

To understand problem consider following view tree.
 ( I use UITableViewController in my application )

Right click and select *open image in new tab* to see large image.
[image]

Bug Info

Right click and select *open image in new tab* to see large image.
[image]

Bug/Problem occurs while performing following navigations.

1. Push one by one view manually and **goto D view**. 
    
   (**PUSH** : Root > Alphabets > A > B > C > D)
2. Pop multiple views at once programmatically using popToViewController and **go back to Root view**. 
    
   (**POP** : Root < Alphabets < A < B < C < D)
3. Push programmatically and **goto 2 view**. 
   (**PUSH** : Root > Numbers > 1 > 2)

in above step 2 and 3 pop and push done programmatically with animation NO, which makes UINavigationBar back button and title very strange.

**NOTE : Above problem occurs only in iOS 7 & work perfectly in iOS 6.**

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem exactly.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the strangeness?

Comment: @nhgrif added code link and application images for better understanding.

Comment: @JuJoDi added code link and application images for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**★☆★　SOLVED　★☆★**

**Reason for problem**

- Doing push or pop inside ***-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated*** method makes navigation stack unstable.

**Solution**

- Create separate method for push or pop related process and call that method from another view controller *(avoid push or pop inside -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated)*
- After push operation call method ***[self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];*** which lays out subviews.

Answer (score 1):

For technical accuracy, one should not call ***layoutSubviews*** directly, even though it does work. Check Apple documentation for more info.